# Cannot SSH anymore, what went wrong?

Tags: ssh

I use to ssh to a remote server (no rsa-key, just password).

Now the server do not accept the connection any more and throw me this error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

While I can google a little to find a fix I can't figure out what went wrong since I haven't touched anything on the machine since last login.

Can you help me find the cause?

**EDIT:** Inspecting the logs I've found these:

```
/var/auth.log
/var/log/auth.log:Dec 26 16:40:32 vps sshd[15567]: error: fork: Cannot allocate memory
/var/log/auth.log:Dec 26 16:41:05 vps sshd[15567]: error: fork: Cannot allocate memory
/var/log/auth.log:Dec 26 16:43:47 vps sshd[15567]: error: fork: Cannot allocate memory
/var/log/auth.log:Dec 27 03:20:06 vps sshd[15567]: error: fork: Cannot allocate memory
/var/log/auth.log:Dec 27 16:15:02 vps sshd[15567]: error: fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

And in the same span-time I've also found *a lot* of these:

```
/var/log/auth.log:Dec 26 13:00:01 vps CRON[1716]: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/security/pam_unix.so): libcrypt.so.1: cannot map zero-fill pages: Cannot allocate memory
/var/log/auth.log:Dec 26 13:00:01 vps CRON[1716]: PAM adding faulty module: /lib/security/pam_unix.so
```

What are these?

Comment: This can mean anything. Most probably, the ssh server is crashing. In the distant past, this could be caused by a bad version of glibc. If it is indeed a crash, there must be some information in dmesh about the segfault.

Comment: Can you still log into it directly?  What do the log files tell you?  What does "ssh -V" tell you?

Comment: @AEP I've seen that caused by a rootkit too, one that replaces glibc.

Comment: I've insepected the logs and found something (I think). Ideas?

Comment: Looks like you're out of RAM.  Can you run "free -m" or something to see if that's the case?

Comment: @Bill Weiss Mmm `free -m` says everything is under control, but it could be since I have only 256mb. Anyway I've just rebooted in order to restart ssh. Can i check some other logs to be sure its a ram issue?

Comment: Do you have any swap space allocated/configured?

Comment: Ugh. I hate VPS servers.

Answer (score 1):

I run DenyHosts on my public ssh servers, and that's the error message I see when an IP has been added to /etc/hosts.deny.

Do you have any similar TCP wrapper services around your SSHd?  Do you have a KVM or serial console to that box?  Or can you SSH in from another server with a different IP?

Comment: I cannot SSH from another server too.

Comment: Got KVM? Serial Console?

Comment: Nope, it's a VPS. I've rebooted it and SSH againt (with success).

Comment: Anyway /ect/hosts.deny wasn't setted.

Comment: Hmm.. Probably SSHd being lame then.  Is it running the latest versions of stuff?